# Expected indent block error python, only used spacing

Tags: python, python-2.7, ipython, indentation

I'm getting a common Python error `expected an indented block`.  I know this is commonly  caused by mixing tabs and spaces... however I know for a fact I only used spaces in this program.

1. I set it so my tabs count as spaces
2. I used multiple formatting programs
3. I then went back through the program and respaced every line of code

Here is the code:

```
class FullHC:
    def __init__(self):
        self.id_clusters = []
        self.blockmodels = []

    def create_hc(G, t=1.0):
    labels=G.nodes()
    ...
```

The line `labels=G.nodes()` is causing the error.  Anytime I put a function where `create_hc` is I get a similar error.

Please let me know if you see something that I don't, as this is really messing with my head.

Thanks so much.

Comment: The issue here isn't mixing tabs and spaces, it that `labels=...` needs to be indented a level deeper (that is, python `expected an indented block`)

Comment: Thanks Daniel. One of those looked at the code for too long errors...

Comment: we've all been there, and there's evidence you tried (google does suggest it would be a space+tabs issue). It's just (un?)fortunate that the error states the exact issue :P

Comment: Yeah you would think that at least one answer would say "umm did you space after your function?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

should be idented, as a first line of a function:

```
class FullHC:
    def __init__(self):
        self.id_clusters = []
        self.blockmodels = []

    def create_hc(G, t=1.0):
        labels=G.nodes()
```